# Is SSDTBI for Visual Studio 2012 Compatible with SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Currently I am creating SSIS packages for SQL server 2014 using Visual Studio 2012 and the SSDTBI for VS2012.This works well.

But I found some compatability issues with VS2012 for SSIS 2014(on web).I'm new to SSIS.I dont know what is that exact issues with VS2012?.And also they mentioned SSIS 2014 is compatible only with VS2013.Here i have mentioned the link below.

http://www.stefanjohansson.org/2015/02/issues-upgrading-an-ssis-solutionpackage-from-visual-studio-2012-to-vs-2013/

http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/201
3/11/13/microsoft-sql-server-data-tools-update.aspx

Can anyone tell me what is exact compatability issues for VS2012 with SSIS 2014?.I can not seem to find anything on google.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[According to msdn it possible.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522577.aspx)

> On an instance of SQL Server 2014, you can import packages from an
>   instance of SQL Server 2008 or from an instance of SQL Server 2012,
>   but you cannot export packages to an instance of SQL Server 2008 or to
>   an instance of SQL Server 2012.

-

> Run packages. You can run SQL Server 2008 Integration Services and SQL
>   Server 2012 Integration Services packages by using the SQL Server 2014
>   version of the dtexec utility or of SQL Server Agent. Whenever a SQL
>   Server 2014 Integration Services tool loads a package that was
>   developed in SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2012, the tool temporarily
>   converts, in memory, the package to the package format that SQL Server
>   2014 Integration Services (SSIS) uses. If the SQL Server 2008 or SQL
>   Server 2012 package has issues that prevent a successful conversion,
>   the SQL Server 2014 Integration Services tool cannot run the package
>   until those issues are resolved. For more information, see Upgrade
>   Integration Services Packages.

However, I would just use VS 2013 if you can.